# How to change password for my Superuser/StackExchange account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I want to change the password for my Superuser/StackExchange account.
Its been 3 years since i changed it -- I know, Unhealthy!

But for the life of me, i can't seem to find the option on "Profile", "Activity" or in "Setting".

Is there a link where i can change the password?

Or is [Account Recovery](https://superuser.com/users/account-recovery) the only option?

There has to be an easier way to change password right?!

Comment: tried https://openid.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven’t actually verified that this works — not today, anyway;
I know I changed my password a couple of years ago (yeah, yeah),
but I’m not sure exactly how I did it — but I believe I found it. 
From your profile page, click on “Edit Profile & Settings”. 
About halfway down the left side, under “SITE SETTINGS”, click on “My Logins”.

[image: “My Logins” page]

This will take you to the “My Logins” page;
you may be able to go directly there [via this link](https://superuser.com/users/mylogins/current). 
Then click on “Change Password”:

[image: “Change Password”]